# How to fix "iteration over non-sequence" in my PySide(Maya) script

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, maya

I am trying to make PySide Ui in Maya looking at different examples of codes, but mine doesn't work,
Problem is that I am getting

```
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "maya console", line 69, in <module>
#   File "maya console", line 32, in create
#   File "maya console", line 61, in __init__
#   File "maya console", line 65, in set_items
# TypeError: iteration over non-sequence #
```

I read few topics about this error and seems to be a problem when people try to iterate thru instance, but since my knowledge in Object-Oriented programming still lacking , I am confused why is it happening in my script.

> ```
> from PySide2 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
> from shiboken2 import wrapInstance
>
> import maya.OpenMaya as om
> import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui
> import maya.cmds as cmds
> import os, functools
>
> def getMayaWindow():
>     pointer = omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
>     if pointer is not None:
>         return wrapInstance(long(pointer), QtWidgets.QWidget)
>
> class testUi():
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.window = 'vl_test'
>         self.title = 'Test Remastered'
>         self.size = (1000, 650)
>
>     def create(self):
>         if cmds.window(self.window, exists=True):
>             cmds.deleteUI(self.window, window=True)
>
>         self.parentWindow = getMayaWindow()
>         self.mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow(self.parentWindow)
>         self.mainWindow.setObjectName(self.window)
>         self.mainWindow.setWindowTitle(self.title)
>
>         self.mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
>         self.mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)
>         self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.mainWidget)
>         testIk = test(self)
>         self.mainLayout.addWidget(testIk)
>
>         self.mainButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
>         self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.mainButton)
>         self.mainButton.clicked.connect(partial(self.load_selected))
>
>         self.mainWindow.show()    
>
>
>
> class test():
>     def __init__(self, maya_transform_nodes=[]):
>         qWid = QtWidgets.QWidget()
>         self.setMinW = qWid.setMinimumWidth(300)
>         self.setMinH = qWid.setMinimumHeight(300)
>         self.sss = qWid.setStyleSheet("border:1px solid rgb(0, 255, 0);")
>         self.items = []
>
>         self.transform_move = QtGui.QTransform()
>         self.transform_scale = QtGui.QTransform()
>
>         self.prev_mouse_pos = QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)
>
>         self.color = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 50, 50)
>         self.clicked_color = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 50, 150)
>         self.right_clicked_color = QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0, 150)
>
>         if maya_transform_nodes:
>             self.set_items(maya_transform_nodes)
>
>
>     def set_items(self, maya_transform_nodes):
>         for path in maya_transform_nodes:
>             print path
>
> v = testUi()
> v.create()
> ```

Expected result would be - I get window , with button which doesn't function and small widget which I wrote in test().

Answer (score 1):

In `testUi.create` you have:

```
testIk = test(self)
```

But `self` is just the class instance of `testUi`.  It is a class, not a list.  But it is being passed as `maya_transform_nodes` in `test`, which expects a list or other iterable.  So either pass it a list (or other iterable), or remove the argument and let it default to `[]`.

Comment: I been taking this idea from another open-source example and if I remove "self" , it will give me an error that  in self.mainLayout.addWidget(testIk) - testIk is not supported signature , should be (PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget), but if I put "self" script runs fine , but giving me that error in "for path in maya_transform_nodes".

Comment: Well, this is unquestionably the problem.  You're passing a class to `test`, which passes it to `test.set_items`, which tries to iterate over it, resulting in the error you saw.  I'm not sure what `addWidget` expects, but you need to understand that you aren't even reaching that code with the existing bug.  So the script doesn't run fine with `self` in place.  Instead, it dies with an error before it ever reaches that code.  So either don't pass `self`, or else stop trying to iterate over it in `test.set_items`.  There really is no other choice.

Comment: I see, thanks , will try to think of way around then :)